# Postgresql - Get MAX Numeric Value on Character Varying Column

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1

I have a column in a Postgresql table that is unique and character varying(10) type.  The table contains old alpha-numeric values that I need to keep.  Every time a new row is created from this point forward, I want it to be numeric only.  I would like to get the max numeric-only value from this table for this column then create a new row with that max value incremented by 1.

Is there a way to query this table for the max numeric value only for this column?

For example, if this column currently has the values:

```
1111
A1111A
1234
1234A
3331
B3332
C-3333
33-D33
3**333*
```

Is there a query that will return 3333, AKA cut out all the non-numeric characters from the values and then perform a MAX() on them?

Answer (score 1):

Not precisely what you asking, but something that I think will work better for you.

To go over all the columns, convert each to numbers, and then cast it to integer & return max.:

```
SELECT MAX(regexp_replace(my_column, '[^0-9]', '', 'g')::int) FROM public.foobar;
```

This gets you your max value... say 2999.

Now, going forward, consider making the default for your column a serial-like value, and convert it to text... that way you set the "MAX" once, and then let postgres do all the work for future values.

```
-- create simple integer sequence
CREATE SEQUENCE public.foobar_my_column_seq
  INCREMENT 1
  MINVALUE 1
  MAXVALUE 9223372036854775807
  START 1
  CACHE 0;

-- use new sequence as default value for column __and__ convert to text
ALTER TABLE foobar 
  ALTER COLUMN my_column 
    SET DEFAULT nextval('publc.foobar_my_column_seq'::regclass)::text;

-- initialize "next value" of sequence to whatever is larger than
-- what you already have in your data ... say 3000:
ALTER SEQUENCE public.foobar_my_column_seq RESTART WITH 3000;
```

Because you're simply setting default, you don't change your current alpha-numeric values.

Answer (score -1):

I figured it out.  The following query works.

```
select text_value, regexp_replace(text_value, '[^0-9]+', '') as new_value from the_table;
```

Result:

```
 text_value            | new_value
-----------------------+-------------
 4*215474              | 4215474
 740024                | 740024
 4*100535              | 4100535
 42356                 | 42356
 CASH                  | 
 4*215474              | 4215474
 740025                | 740025
 740026                | 740026
 4*5089655798          | 45089655798
 4*15680               | 415680
 4*224034              | 4224034
 4*265718708           | 4265718708
```

Comment: you'll want to set the global flag 'g' in the regexp as otherwise it converts only the first non-numeric within a string.